# $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \to \infty \longleftrightarrow a_n>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm wondering how to prove the following and if it's true anyway:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence where $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then:
>   $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} = 1 $$

I was wondering if it can be proved since $a_n$ itself doesn't have to converge at all.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any asumptions on $a_n$, this is not true: Let $(b_n)$ your favourite, positive sequence and $a_n = b_n^n$. Then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=b_n$ behaves arbitrary (as $b_n$ was arbitrary).

But something can be said: If $(a_n)$ is bounded above and away from zero, that is, there are $\alpha, A > 0$ with $\alpha \le a_n \le A$ for all $n$, then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 1$. Note that 
$$ \sqrt[n]\alpha \le \sqrt[n]{a_n}\le \sqrt[n]A $$
and both the left and the right hand side converge to $1$. Hence, by the sandwitch theorem $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 1$ also.

Comment: This is also true if $a_n$ is polynomially bounded.

Comment: @LutzL True, thanks. So we can replace $\alpha$ and $A$ by polynomials $A(n)$, $\alpha(n)$, with $\alpha(n) > 0$.